# How to join a user to already created video call session in Quickblox?

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am going to make an user join already started group call.

For example, first user A creates video group call with user B and C, and then user D is going to join this group call.
Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, we can add other user run time as well, so for that we don't need to do anything, just follow my instructions.Like USER A call USER B and USER C , then USER A want to add USER D into the Call for that, USER A just need to place call to USER D,after that USER D will automatically added to the call.

Comment: Hi @sunny verma, can you explain how user A place call to user D?

Comment: Hey, you just need to call the method to place call    QBRTCSession session =
                    QBRTCClient.getInstance(context).createNewSessionWithOpponents(314432, qbConferenceType);

            session.startCall(session.getUserInfo());

Comment: @PaulStein: Did you get the solution for this?

Comment: @VijaySinghRana, there is no joining solution. I moved to webrtc service.